# Call methods from the same unique thread

Tags: java, multithreading, methods, parameters, callable

I have a service like this with many methods:

```
public class MyService {
 public void method1(String arg0, int arg1) {...}
 public MyObject method2(Object arg0, String arg1, int arg2) {...}
 //...
}
```

By now methods of MyService are called from various threads (Eclipse RCP context).
My need is to call all the methods of that service from the same unique thread.

I ve seen SingleThreadExecutor but will I have to define each method as a Callable and create a Class for each method? Plus, I don't know how to pass various arguments to my methods?
Of course all calls to theses methods should get the returned value (if one) and exceptions as it is now.

Is there an easy solution that would transform all calls like this:

```
myService.method1(arg0, arg1);
```

to something like this:

```
executor.execute(myService.method1(arg0, arg1))
```

I would appreciate some example.

Answer (score 0):

If you're compiling with Java8, you can simplify the `execute` calls by using lambda expressions:

```
executor.execute(() -> myService.method1(arg0, arg1));
```

In Java7 or older, you can use an anonymous inner class which is not quite as clean:

```
executor.execute(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        myService.method1(arg0, arg1);
    }
});
```

Either way, what you're doing is submitting an object that implements `Runnable`, and with a `run()` method that calls the method in question.

Comment: Thx that looks like what I was looking for.
Finally I did that way with callable:
    Future<MyObject> result = (Future<MyObject>) myExecutor.submit(() ->         
       {
       MyObject myObject;
    try {
     myObject = myService.method1(arg0, arg1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
     LOG.error();
    }
                              return myObject;
 });
 result.get();

The problem I have now, I don't know how to handle exception outside the callable.
Do you have any idea?

Comment: @Zibus69, that should be a new question, but if you submit a `Callable` to the `ExecutorService` instead of submitting a `Runnable`, you'll get back a `Future` object.  You can use the future to wait for either a return value or an exception.